How to resize a Bayer image(raw image) directly in opencv?
This may be a simple question, but I have a problem when resizing a bayer image(RGGB) resided in a cv::Mat with CV_8UC1 type. That is I get a gray image after resized when shown with cv::imshow (before show it I convert the reiszedimg to a bgr image).
Resizing bayer image codes:
cv::resize(bayerimg, resizedimg, cv::Size(), 0.6, 0.8);

I think it is because the special structure of bayer image, so one cannot use the resize operation from opencv directly on a bayer image.
If so, how can I resize a bayer image to random ratial directly, is there any algorithm for this task?
Besize, I want a c++ solution, thank you, guys.

I have tried
cv::resize(bayerimg, resizedimg, cv::Size(), 0.6, 0.8);
cv::cvtColor(resizedimg, bgr, cv::COLOR_BayerBG2BGR);
cv::imshow("rawimg", bgr);
cv::waitKey(0);

But only get a gray image. What is wrong.

Basically no you can't do that to a Bayer image. You can downscale them by powers of 2 and upscale them by integer values if you want by interpolation. You have to go through a 24 bit colour representation to do any more general rescaling by other ratios.

@MartinBrown Thank you, but it sounds frustrating.

I'm curious, what's the reason you'd want to do that?

@DanMašek, Firstly I need efficiency when transferring bayer image from backend device to front-end desktop application via tcp protocol. Bayer image is generated by camera at first place, and it is very efficient transferred by ethernet. Secondly, to show it on a desktop widget suitably, I have to downscale it to fit my window. So I resize it at first and then convert to rgb, again due to efficiency(cause downscale can reduce resolution of image), I think?

Right, for archiving or transfer of the unmodified image, it makes sense to leave it mosaiced. But you can't use any normal processing algorithms unless you demosaic it, and once you've done that, it makes little sense to go back (and is non-trivial if you don't want to degrade the quality severely). At that point just use an existing (lossy, since you don't seem to mind that) compressor and you'll be better off both quality and compression level wise.

voting to close. some things are impossible or defy logic. raw bayer-patterned sensor data cannot be resized without debayering. if OP wants the "can't be done" as an actual answer... I won't stand in the way.

bayer image needed to be a valid type to be able to resize like rgb, gray scale etc. here is a video which may help to understand the logic of bayer

@MartinBrown  I think it can be resized to a even size. For example, 1616 bayer image can be resized to 1414, 1212 and so on. To achieve this, just imaging 1616 image consisting of blocks which is a 2*2 square, and when calculating we treat that small blocks as pixel just like that in rgb image. The only flaw is that the resized size should be even number.

My statement of divide by 2^N only was slightly too restrictive. It can be cleanly downscaled by any even common factors of the image dimensions. That way you can average over 2x2 3x3 or NxN of the 2x2 RGGB Bayer blocks and output one spatial average Bayer block for each NxN input block. You can potentially scale down by any integer divisor by pretending that the 2x2 pixel blocks at the very edges of the image are repeated off to infinity. This might even do what you want if the intention is to reduce bandwidth from the remote sensor to a host display. Such binning is often done 2x2 or 4x4.

@CristophRackwitz Actually it can be cleanly down sampled by any even common divisor 2N of both the width and the height by averaging NxN 2x2 Bayer sub-blocks together into one Bayer block, or if you don't care about altering the aspect ratio by any even number.  Some creative padding is needed at the edges if dimensions are not an exact multiple of the divisor.

@MartinBrown Yes, I think that idea is very useful in my situation. Thanks.

@MartinBrown present this then. I'm sure there will be issues that cause artefacts, that wouldn't happen with debayering, then resampling. bayer patterns can't just be "binned". present your solution first. then I'll present data to show the issues.

this may help have a common basis for discussion: https://www.1stvision.com/cameras/IDS/IDS-manuals/en/basics-binning.html and https://www.1stvision.com/cameras/IDS/IDS-manuals/uEye_Manual/hw_binning.html -- the binning (e.g. 2x2) they present causes the "shift" of the color planes to shift additionally, in an amount that differs from how the data would look, if the sensor were half by half resolution in the first place. debayering first, then "binning" (resampling), will look different from "binning" on the bayer pattern itself, and then debayering.

@christofrackwitz I don't disagree with you that a better result would be obtained by going through a de-Bayered 24bit full resolution  colour image, but if the OP is trying to minimise bandwidth and doesn't care about some artefacts then binning the Bayer masked image is another option. It may not be good enough for his needs but I think it is worth trying.  I will post a toy version of Bayer binning when I get around to it.

in Python this would be so easy to express. slicing with stride, some summing, some assignments, done. alas, C++ and OpenCV's dated API.

This represents a bare bones proof of concept method to sum Bayer images and make a subsampled one scaled to be  smaller by an integer factor. The width and height should be divisible by the chosen scale factor or the right hand edge and bottom line will be corrupted (the latter may cause access faults). It can handle independent scaling for width and height.
It accepts raw Bayer mask data as an array of unsigned char and returns one scaled down by nx and ny in a similar fashion. Only handles the binary data you have to provide it with the dimensions from the header.
I think it will somewhat distort the phase of the red and blue channels when scale factors are even numbers but that it should be a fairly good approximation for odd scale factors. I'd be interested to see how it performs on actual raw Bayer images. I'm aware that plenty of test patterns can be constructed to make it fail (but the same applies to all Bayer masked data).
I expect the results to be inferior to reconstructing the full 24 bit RGB colour image and then resampling it according to the Bayer rules but I think that they might well be acceptable for some purposes (albeit at lower resolution and smaller physical size). It might do what the OP wants if he can live with the chroma edge artefacts that will be introduced.
The code has only had the most cursory testing but reproduces expected results on the snippet of test data included in the code. It has only been tested for nx, ny = 2,3 and on tiny amounts of data.  Here is the code:
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char test[] = { 0, 1, 2, 4,       1, 16, 2, 32,  48, 64, 72, 96,  128, 0, 128, 64,
                         5, 6, 7, 8,       1, 0, 2, 0,    64, 48, 96, 72,  0, 128, 64, 128,
                         8, 9, 10, 11,     4, 64, 8, 128, 64, 48, 96, 72,  0, 128, 64, 128,
                         12, 13, 14, 255,  3,0, 4, 0, 0,   0,  4,  4,128,  1, 23, 54,  1,
                         1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5,7, 9, 11 }; // extras added for testing 3x3

void DebugPrint(const char *name, unsigned char* buffer, int n, int m=99999)
{
   if (n > 100) return;
   printf("\nDebug Print: %s\n",name);
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // dump n elements of array in linear form or line break every m
   {
       if (!(i % m)) printf("\n");
       printf("%4u", buffer[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}

void DownSampleBayer(unsigned char* inbuff, unsigned char* outbuff, int width, int height, int nx, int ny)
{
   int norm = nx * ny;
   if (width <= 16) {
       printf("\nTesting with dimensions %i x %i scale factors nx = %i, ny = %i", width, height, nx, ny);
       DebugPrint("original", test, width * height, width);
   }
   if (width % nx) printf("warning: width %i is not a multple of scale factor %i\n", width, nx);
   if (height % nx) printf("warning: height %i is not a multple of scale factor %i\n", height, ny);
   for (int iy = 0; iy < height; iy += 2*ny)
   for (int ix = 0; ix < width; ix += 2*nx) // inner loop processes Nx x Ny 2x2 Bayer blocks
   {   
       int isx = iy * width + ix;           // source Bayer array index
       int idx = (ix + iy*width / ny) / nx; // destination Bayer array index

       unsigned int x00, x01, x10, x11;  // Bayer block x00 x01
       x00 = x01 = x11 = x10 = 0;        //             x01 x11
    
       for (int j = 0; j < 2 * ny * width; j += 2 * width) // sum over ny blocks down
       {
           for (int k = 0; k < 2 * nx; k += 2)     // sum over nx blocks across
           {
               int ibay = isx + j + k;
               x00 += inbuff[ibay];
               x01 += inbuff[ibay + 1];
               x10 += inbuff[ibay + width];
               x11 += inbuff[ibay + width + 1];
           }
       }
   
       outbuff[idx] = (x00+norm/2) / norm;
       outbuff[idx + 1] = (x01 + norm / 2) / norm;
       outbuff[idx + width / nx] = (x10 + norm / 2) / norm;
       outbuff[idx + width / nx + 1] = (x11 + norm / 2) / norm;
   }
   DebugPrint("out scaled array", outbuff, width * height / norm, width / nx);
   DebugPrint("out linear", outbuff, 20);
}

int main()
{
 // subject only to very limted testing on test[] data above
 // assumes that test is a raw consecutive byte Bayer masked data array
 // outputs a new Bayer array downscaled by nx in width and ny in height.
 // the resulting array averages over each component in turn
 // appears to work OK for nx,ny = 2 or 3 untested beyond that or for large arrays

   unsigned char outbuff[100];
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) outbuff[i] = 0;
   DownSampleBayer(test, outbuff, 16, 4, 2, 2);
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) outbuff[i] = 0;
   DownSampleBayer(test, outbuff, 12, 6, 3, 3);
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) outbuff[i] = 0;
   DownSampleBayer(test, outbuff, 6, 12, 3, 3);  
 }

I'm curious to see what artefacts this treatment produces on normal images. I'm pretty sure that there will be some along the lines of the links that @ChristophRackwitz has already posted. I suspect 2x subsampling is a worst case for deBayering and that 3x might be quite close to being well behaved.
The assumptions that go into deBayering have clearly been violated so sharp black to white edge transitions will suffer from chromatic artefacts (all Bayer images do to some extent).
Thinking about it some more whist writing this post I reckon I can create a weighted summation to get a much closer estimate to what a larger Bayer sensor would have actually measured. Anyway this toy code should be enough for a discussion of whether or not the artefacts are tolerable or a more sophisticated treatment is needed. That would require knowing the Bayer pattern to treat R, G, B correctly whereas simple binning doesn't.
